# Electrical problem - loss of power to fixture and outlet

Tags: electrical

Hot to ground and neutral to ground read 120 V. Hot to neutral 0 V. This is a portion of a circuit that appears to be at the end of the wiring. An overhead light/fan and one duplex outlet are not working and show the above readings. Everything else on that circuit appears to be working properly, with voltage between hot and neutral and hot and ground 120 V and 0 V neutral to ground. That portion was working until a few days ago.

Comment: That's a good description of an anomolous situation but you might want to actually ask a question so we know what part you need help with.

Comment: Ah, well I'm somewhat familiar with electric wiring but far from expert. My question is: how can I correct this problem and get my light, fan and outlet back "on"? I have a multimeter and tools.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the question.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral to ground should never read 120V. This means your neutral connection back to the breaker/fuse box has gotten disconnected somehow. That needs to be found and fixed.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't that cause a problem for the entire circuit? All the other outlets and fixtures on that circuit appear to be working fine. Voltage measurements of the few outlets I've checked appear to be correct, also.

Comment: Depends on where the loose connection is in the circuit, relative to those other outlets/fixtures. If what you've told us is correct, It Needs To Be Fixed.

Comment: Thanks again. I concur that it needs to be fixed ASAP. I suspect the outlet which is a location that can't be reached easily. I've checked the light/fan wall switch and the fixture itself. I'm keeping the circuit off until I locate the problem. Old house, hard to trace wiring. I'll keep after it.